# Can I deploy an HTML5 game with Xamarin products?

Tags: html, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin, 2d-games

I have an HTML5 game in the works and was wondering if it would make sense to try and use Xamarin products for deploying my app to iOS, Android and Windows Phone.

- Do Xamarin products support this?
- Would I gain anything from using Xamarin products as a wrapper? Ease of deployment, native API access, etc.
- How would performance be for a simple side scrolling 2D platformer?

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin could be used to wrap an HTML game, but I don't think it makes sense.  Bear in mind that with Xamarin you would have to rewrite the UI component for each platform, so in your case you'd manually have to render within a `UIWebView` on iOS, a `WebView` on Android, and so on for each platform you want to support.

Possibly look into other solutions, such as [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/), which are squarely aimed at wrapping applications written using the HTML stack.  These are likely to have solved many of the problems that you would encounter by trying, using Xamarin or otherwise, to make a wrapper yourself.